# For Monogame or XNA is there a pattern for spawnng outside of main function

Tags: c#, design-patterns, xna, monogame

Hoping i worded the question ok.
Looking for ideas how to avoid having all the Draw() and Update() code in the main game1 class.

I've made subclasses, and put Update and Draw commands in those, but they still seem to have to be wired up to the Main Update/Draw functions.

Is there a pattern for creating entities and having the entity control more of what it is doing?
Or maybe an event/delegate pattern?
Or something like the prefab items in Unity?

I may not be asking in the correct terms or just missing that 'ah ha' idea moment, new to Monogame, was trying Unity2D, and the had prefab items. I more use to designing web application and such, gaming seems more like console programming with the Main start function.

**UPDATE**

Just wanted to update what i used.

I gave Artemis a good try, but i just did not go well for me. I would suggest others try it as well, you may find it to your liking. But being an OO programmer for a long time, i'm just more combfortable and faster with using the GameComponent and DrawableGameComponent. Personally, i've gotten more accomplished with OO in less time then trying to get understand ECS.

For the spawning, for now, in my main game could is a just a for loop to instantiate my game entites, and then use components.Add(yourentity), this was the part i was stumbling on.

Artemis, its interesting, i can see its appeal. But I just don't like uncoupling properties into another class, just to add that class back to the entity as a collection. Especially since I'm using C# which is designed to be more OO then an ECS.

But try Artemis, Unity and  xna GameComponents. They all offer unique ways of building games, just pick what fits your program best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you're seeing is that the game controls the Update and Draw loops. In order for your entities to control these, you have two options.

The first, is to use a [Drawble Game Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent.aspx) for your entities, which automatically gets the draw and update functions called by the game loop.

The second is to do the same thing by hand - create a pool of all entities, and when your main game gets the Update or Draw calls, it goes through that pool and calls the Update and Draw functions for the given Entities. As long as you're careful with overrides to Dispose unhooking them, you can also achieve the same result via OnUpdate and OnDraw events in your main game.

What Unity does is a step further - instead of Entities, Components have control of their Update and Draw calls, and are associated by Entity. This grow closer to the ECS framework, which you should look into. For the C# implementation of this framework, see:

- [Artemis](http://thelinuxlich.github.io/artemis_CSharp/)
- [Jacinth](https://github.com/aravol/Jacinth) (of my own design)

Comment: Nice touch mentioning ECS frameworks. I believe they are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, hopefull get to try out each tonight. Probably go with the DrawableGameComponent since my game is a small 2D game. I'll try both and post some results.

Comment: In Artemis tutorial 'StarWarrior', i'm having trouble understanding RenderSytem() and EntityProcessingSystem? Not even sure where Render System is called from, and Don't see a EntityProcessingSystem class any where. I can see how it may work, but in win7 i can;t get it to run, so i can not debug it.

Comment: You won't see the Render System called directly, and EntityProccessingSystem is a part of the Artemis libraries. The Render system is called when the EntityWorld performs the draw loop, and hooks in by finding it (and all other systems) via an assembly scan during initialization. Thus, any system with the appropriate attributes will get called.

Comment: The link to Artemis appears to be dead

Comment: @josaphatv how sad, Artemis was the definitive implementation. I'll replace with a link to my own project, Jacinth.